# TFS Could not connect to database

Tags: tfs

On my home machine I have lost the databases that were mapped to tfs2010.
Now it says that I cannot connect to database.

Need to create Collection but does not allow me.

how can I proceed without reinstalling tfs2010 all over again?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather this is was a single-server installation, i.e. database and app server on the same machine? If so, if the database tables are truly gone (deleted) then there's nothing you can do I'm afraid, because "everything" was in them (work items, source code, you name it). Anything you had stored there is gone anyway, so you might as well re-install TFS.

Before doing anything this radical, I would open SQL Server Manager and look for the databases. Maybe you have backups of them?

Answer (score 0):

There is a DB named TFS_Configuration that stores the TFS server lever configuration.  If you lost that than you will need to uninstall then re-install TFS and run the configuration wizard;  the TFS install used to be a pain,  but as of TFS 2010 it is easy now - if you just reinstalling it like this it will be straightforward.